# How do I change the way that the RotatingFileHandler names files in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I want to change the way that the rotating file handler names files.

For example, if I use RotatingFileHandler, it separates the log file when it reaches a specific file size naming "log file name + extension numbering", like below.

```
filename.log      #first log file
filename.log.1    #rotating log file1
filename.log.2    #rotating log file2
```

However, I want the log handler to name them every time it is created.
For example.

```
09-01-12-20.log    #first log file
09-01-12-43.log    #rotating log file1
09-01-15-00.log    #rotating log file2
```

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

I am not asking how to create and name a file.

I want to facilitate python `logging` package doing something like inheriting and overriding `logging`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I inherit and override `RotatingFileHandler` of python logging handler.

RotatingFileHandler has `self.baseFilename` value, the handler will use `self.baseFilename` to create logFile.(when it creates file first or when rollover happens)

`self.shouldRollover()` method, It checks if the handler should rollover logfile or not.

If this method `return 1`, it means rollover should happen or `return 0`.

By overriding them, I define when this handler makes rollover and which name should be used for new log file by rollover.

*-----------------------------------------Edit-----------------------------------------*

I post the example code.

```
from logging import handlers

class DailyRotatingFileHandler(handlers.RotatingFileHandler):

    def __init__(self, alias, basedir, mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=0):
        """
        @summary: 
        Set self.baseFilename to date string of today.
        The handler create logFile named self.baseFilename
        """
        self.basedir_ = basedir
        self.alias_ = alias

        self.baseFilename = self.getBaseFilename()

        handlers.RotatingFileHandler.__init__(self, self.baseFilename, mode, maxBytes, backupCount, encoding, delay)

    def getBaseFilename(self):
        """
        @summary: Return logFile name string formatted to "today.log.alias"
        """
        self.today_ = datetime.date.today()
        basename_ = self.today_.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ".log" + '.' + self.alias_
        return os.path.join(self.basedir_, basename_)

    def shouldRollover(self, record):
        """
        @summary: 
        Rollover happen 
        1. When the logFile size is get over maxBytes.
        2. When date is changed.

        @see: BaseRotatingHandler.emit
        """

        if self.stream is None:                
            self.stream = self._open()

        if self.maxBytes > 0 :                  
            msg = "%s\n" % self.format(record)
            self.stream.seek(0, 2)  
            if self.stream.tell() + len(msg) >= self.maxBytes:
                return 1

        if self.today_ != datetime.date.today():
            self.baseFilename = self.getBaseFilename()
            return 1

        return 0
```

This DailyRotatingFileHandler will create logfile like

```
2016-10-05.log.alias
2016-10-05.log.alias.1
2016-10-05.log.alias.2
2016-10-06.log.alias
2016-10-06.log.alias.1
2016-10-07.log.alias.1
```

Comment: @FredFury  I add an example code, It hopes it could help you.

Answer (score -2):

Check the following code and see if it helps. As far as I could understand from your question if your issue is in achieving the filename based on timestamp then this shall work for you.

```
import datetime, time
# This return the epoch timestamp    
epochTime = time.time()
# We generate the timestamp 
# as per the need
timeStamp = datetime.datetime\
                    .fromtimestamp(epochTime)\
                    .strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
# Create a log file 
# use timeStamp as filename
fo = open(timeStamp+".log", "wb")
fo.write("Log data")
fo.close()
```

Comment: I already know how to handle time and create file but What I want is with Python logging facilating Python logging functions. it can be something like inheriting logging class and overriding logging method.