# Properly configuring file paths and names for python logger

Tags: python

I have the following `.yaml` file defining my configurations for the logger I want to use.

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False

formatters:
    simple:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(module)12s - %(name)12s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: debug_format
        stream: ext://sys.stdout

    info_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: simple
        interval: 1
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8
        when: midnight
        filename: Log/info.log

    error_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: ERROR
        formatter: error_format
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8
        filename: Log/errors.log

loggers:
    dedalus_logger:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [console]
        propagate: false

root:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console, info_file_handler, error_file_handler]
```

The problem with this is that my `RotatingFileHandler`, and `TimedRotatingFileHandler` will name the files as `info.log2`, and `info.log.2017.10.19`,

**How** can I make it so the names are not set automatically like that but instead have a form that makes more sense, like `info.2.log`, and `info.2017.10.19.log`.

**Lastly** I am defining the `filename` as `Log/info.log` if I run my app like this

```
>>cd Module/src
>>python run.py
```

It will create the log files where I expect them inside `Module/src/Log`. If instead I run it like this though

```
>> python Module/src/run.py
```

it will try to create the log files in my current directory, which is not what I want, how can I properly configure the logger to fix these two issues?

Comment: For the second issue you can probably specify full address of the log file where you want to log them like - `/var/log/my_app/info.log`. Or you can use the `__name__` variable while setting log file name.

Comment: If I were to always create them in a standard directory then yes you solution is correct, but I would want it to be in the same directory with the program itself.

Comment: This should help with your first problem, where you can override the `RotatingFileHandler` class and customize the log file names as you want.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294275/naming-rotating-log-files-specific-name-in-python

Comment: You can use something like this - `os.path.basename(__file__)` or `sys.argv[0]`, as a base reference for log file. Then no matter where your main file is the log file will be created with respect to that file.